# Automating Hive Activity using aws

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-data-pipeline

I would like to automate my hive script every day , in order to do that i have an option which is data pipeline. But the problem is there that i am exporting data from dynamo-db to s3 and with a hive script i am manipulating this data. I am giving this input and output in hive-script that's where the problem starts because a hive-activity has to have input and output but i have to give them in script file.

I am trying to find a way to automate this hive-script and waiting for some ideas ?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you tried executing the hive step as an emr activity by providing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable staging on Hive Activity to run any arbitrary Hive Script.

```
stage = false
```

Do something like:

```
{
  "name": "DefaultActivity1",
  "id": "ActivityId_1",
  "type": "HiveActivity",
  "stage": "false",
  "scriptUri": "s3://baucket/query.hql",
  "scriptVariable": [
    "param1=value1",
    "param2=value2"
  ],
  "schedule": {
    "ref": "ScheduleId_l"
  },
  "runsOn": {
    "ref": "EmrClusterId_1"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the Hive Activity, is to use an EMR activity as in the following example:

```
{
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "DefaultSchedule"
      },
      "name": "EMR Activity name",
      "step": "command-runner.jar,hive-script,--run-hive-script,--args,-f,s3://bucket/path/query.hql",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "EmrClusterId"
      },
      "id": "EmrActivityId",
      "type": "EmrActivity"
    }
```