# What to use for exporting DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I would like to create a data pipeline which will export data from dynamoDB and import it to s3. everything seems fine but there is a problem because , my data on dynamoDB is binary and pipeline settings , there is not accepted data type as binary.

What can i do about it ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Hive Script that exports data from dynamoDB to S3. ([Samples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html))

You would need to disable staging to run your own Hive Script ([An example to do this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014129/1772454)).