# Scheduling an EMR Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I have built and stored queries using HIVE and PIG that I would like to schedule to run on a weekly basis. The scripts create S3 files and update DynamoTables. What can I use to create an AmazonEMR Cluster to auto run these scripts on a scheduled basis.

I was thinking AWS Data Pipeline but it seems to require creation of data nodes and I do not think that would necessary for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to specify data nodes if you disable staging on HiveActivity.

> stage = false

Please see [the example in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014129/1772454).